# PHP If state - Render HTML only if there is text output from Joomla module text field int the backend

Tags: php, joomla, module

I try to build a simple FAQ Module in Joomla 3.

I have 4 fields in the module backend. "Question 1 & Answer 1" "Question 2 & Answer 2".

My php and Html is build like this:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3 class="question"> <?php echo $params->get('question1'); ?></h3>
  <div  class="question">
  <?php echo $params->get('answer1'); ?>
  </div>

  <h3  class="question"> <?php echo $params->get('question2'); ?></h3>
  <div  class="question">
  <?php echo $params->get('answer2'); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

I like to add some php with a if statement so the code block only renders if the textfields in the backend if they are filled out from the user:

(If the field "question3" have any text, show this code)

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('question3')) : ?>  //This is the line of code i do not know how to do.
  <h3  class="question"> <?php echo $params->get('question2'); ?></h3>
  <div  class="question">
  <?php echo $params->get('answer2'); ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This is how the XML looks like:

```
                <!-- Question 1 -->                 
                <field
                    label="Question 1"
                    default=""
                    name="question1"
                    description="Fill in the question"
                    type="text"
                    size="60"   
                />
                <!-- End of Question 1 -->

                <!-- Answer 1 -->                   
                <field
                    label="Answer1" 
                    default="Fill in the answer"
                    name="answer1"
                    description="Fill in the answer"
                    type="editor"
                    width="200"
                    height="100"
                    hide="readmore,pagebreak" 
                    filter="safehtml" 
                    size="260"  
                />
                <!-- End of Answer 1 -->

                <field type="spacer" name="questionspacer2" label="&lt;b&gt;Question and Answer 2 1&lt;/b&gt;" />


                    <!-- Question 2 -->                 
                <field
                    label="Question 2"
                    default=""
                    name="question2"
                    description="Fill in the question"
                    type="text"
                    size="60"   
                />
                <!-- End of Question 2 -->

<!-- Answer 2 -->                   
                <field
                    label="Answer2" 
                    default=""
                    name="answer2"
                    description="Fill in the answer"
                    type="editor"
                    width="200"
                    height="100"
                    hide="readmore,pagebreak" 
                    filter="safehtml" 
                    size="260"  
                />
                <!-- End of Answer 2 -->
```

Any hint would be great! I am already looking all night for a solution.

Comment: You are looking for `isset();` and `empty();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you set the parameters if not filled you need to check the output like this:

```
$answer2 = $params->get('answer2'));

// (Applies if the not filled data returns NULL etc.)
if ( isset($answer2) ) { YOUR CODE } 

// (Applies if the not filled data returns an empty string)
if ( !empty($answer2) ) { YOUR CODE }
```

not tested, but it should work ;)

EDIT: Just made this how it should look like, just as discussed in the comments below :)

Comment: After i do this: 
if ( isset($params->get('answer2')) ) {echo $params->get('answer2'); }  I get an error: Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context.

Comment: Try to assign the output into a variable:
`$answer2 = $params->get('answer2);`... then use `if (!empty($answer2)){...}` or `if (isset($answer2)){...}`. I don't really know what is returned if you get the 'answer'... In my example I'm thinking of a simple string, since you simply echo it out up there ;)

Comment: The isset + variable version works wonderful! You made my day, thank you very much!